# Can't override forgettin password for Postgresql on Mac

Tags: postgresql, terminal

I am having an issue where I forgot the password to the postgres shell when trying to login as postgres. I looked online and found several different things to do, but none of it worked. I have messed with the `pg_hba.conf` file but even with that change, it is not working. Here is what my pg_hba.conf file looks like.

```
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.

# CAUTION: Configuring the system for local "trust" authentication
# allows any local user to connect as any PostgreSQL user, including
# the database superuser.  If you do not trust all your local users,
# use another authentication method.


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

and then i ran the follwoing command:

`brew services restart postgres`

and I keep getting the following error:

`omars-MacBook-Pro:postgres omarjandali$ psql -U postgres Password for user postgres:  psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Anyone know how to fix this issue.

Comment: The pg_hba.conf you show is not actually in effect.  Either you edited the wrong file, or your restart didn't do anything, or you have multiple servers and are connecting to the wrong one, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your command `psql -U postgres` is attempting to make a socket connection, however you've only got `trust` authentication set up for TCP/IP connections on `localhost`.

Try `psql -h localhost -U postgres`.

Alternatively, add a line to `pg_hba.conf` setting up `trust` authentication for socket connections:

```
host    all             all                                    trust
```

and restart PostgreSQL (though you don't actually need to restart it, `pg_ctl -D /path/to/data-directory reload` should work if you know the actual data directory path).